# How to find the nodejs driver version?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi everyone? I'm new on mongoLab, and i have a database connected with a sandbox plan with mongodb 3.2 version. I'm getting a warning message about the upgrade to mongodb 3.4 soon. After looking deep into compatibilities changes that are needed (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/), i find out i need to make sure that the Node Js driver version i'm using will be suitable with MongoDB 3.4. According to this doc https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility, the nodejs driver that i need is 2.2.12.
Does someone know how to check the nodejs driver version in a nodejs app.

Answer (score 5):

Check your `package.json` file. Depending on what package you're using, it might be:

- mongoose
- mongoDB
- or even some of [these](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongo)

Comment: Thank you Lazyexpert. In the mongoose and mongodb  package.json files i have "_nodeVersion": "6.0.0". Is that the nodejs driver version??

Comment: @Gus nono, you have to check package.json in your root app folder

Comment: Got it thank you again Lazyexpert

Comment: I have installed mongodb 4.0... So the mongoDB version in `package.json` matters?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet there is no mongoDB version in `package.json` you may find what driver (npm module) you're using to access mongo in `package.json` and it's version.

Comment: And if I am using mongoose to access ? then its version matters?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

Comment: @Lazyexpert I didn't see any info about node.js driver in package.json. Can you explain little more?